# Why is tapping on build version of emulator 7 times is not enabling developer option in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm using emulators with android version 11, 12 and 13 (Pixel 4, 6). And in all of them I can't enable developer option, because tapping on build version of the emulator is not working

I followed steps: Settings->About emulated device->Android version-> tapping on build number is impossible

Comment: define impossible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two build numbers one in the android version and one as mentioned below.

following this on pixel 6 with android 13 emulator worked just fine:

> Settings-> scroll down to get to About emulated device-> then press 7 times

[image: check this for reference]